# UIButton shadow not drawing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I'm attempting to create a method to configure buttons in an app. My method performs as expected, but the shadows don't draw. It does not crash.

I've created a `UIButton` `extension` with the following method:

```
func configureWhiteText(withBackgroundColor buttonColor: UIColor?) {
    // basic configuration
    tintColor = UIColor.white
    setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    backgroundColor = buttonColor

    // layer stuff
    layer.drawsAsynchronously = true
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
    layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
}
```

I've tried it within a `UITableViewController` in `viewDidLoad` and 'viewWillAppear` without luck:

```
myButton.configureWhiteText(withBackgroundColor: UIColor.blue)
```

The buttons are in grouped static cells of `UITableViewController`. Everything works within the configuration method except the shadow-oriented lines of code. `layer.cornerRadius` rounds the corner as expected, but none of the other `layer`-oriented lines draw a shadow.

I've verified `layer.masksToBounds = false`. I also tried commenting out `layer.drawsAsynchronously` and `layer.shouldRasterize` to no avail.

Any further ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Like the answers below, all you need to do is just to add a one line of code. You can refer to this [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-shadow-to-a-uiview) for more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You left out the setting that actually turns on the shadow — the `shadowOpacity`. Add this line:

```
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

Badda bing badda boom.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something, but WOW! LOL. I feel like this right now--> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IS7Og1zvdy8

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the shadow path, assuming it is in an uibutton extension

```
self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 20).CGPath
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added that line and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

For someone, like me, who might still face the same issue even if layer.shadowOpacity is set to a non-zero value. If your button background color is UIColor.clear, you should change it to other colors, e.g. white color.